# QFrame is not getting drawn under vertical scroll bar

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, frame

Image of `QFrame` issue:

[image: Image of QFrame Issue]

I am putting a frame around the window and my window is having a scrollbar (vertical scrollbar only).

I have set the `QFrame` styling as

```
QFrame {
    border: 8px solid gray;
}
```

and for styling of scrollbar I have used [customizing-qscrollbar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar).

Now I am seeing that there a white line at the bottom of the scrollbar next to the down arrow. The same line is not there above the up arrow of scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a corner widget was causing the above issue.
Since i found the fix, i would like to share.

```
QAbstractScrollArea::corner {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```